# Unwind in Xcode 7 Using Swift 2 Does not Work

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have two View Controllers. In the second View Controller, I have a button called "Gidelim". I want it to turn back to the first View Controller when I click on it.

For this purpose, I have defined a func in the first View Controller's as below:

[The Unwind Segue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6df2.png)

The func "YeniVCAc" shows the second View Controller and it works. The func "ilkVCGit" has to return back to this View Controller.

I have CTRL-dragged the button to the Exit on the second view controller. Then I have chosen ilkVCGit.

This design must be correct as I think. However, the application crashes when I press the button on the second view controller.

Comment: What is the crash message?

Comment: It's the casual message as: bla bla 0x00000001111db92d start + 1
 21  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connect your button in the Interface Builder to this Action, in the class of your SecondViewController:

```
@IBAction func dismiss(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the feedback. It should work. However, I am still wondering why the design above does not work.